# Adding multiple styles to a div in css

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

I'm kinda stuck at the moment. I'm trying to create a navigation bar for my first site.

In the body of the html i have

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> 
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Now my css is

```
#navbar {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
```

But i would also like to add

```
a:hover,a:active { 
background-color:#7A8B8B;
```

Which currently is applied to any link on the page not just those in the navigation bar. How do i go about applying the hover link style just to #navbar.

Thanks!

Comment: :active :focus :hove these are all properties of anchor element... It only applicable of 'a' tag not for 'ul > li' tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
#navbar a:hover,#navbar a:active { 
  background-color:#7A8B8B;
}
```

Which means apply these styles to the a tags contained in the element with the id of `navbar`

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T5DHh/)

Comment: Thanks, is there a way i can structure the css file to have both #navbar styles contained together?

Comment: do you mean just in one file or have it one block?

Comment: Just in one block in the main css file. Thanks :)

Comment: No each "block" targets elements with specific styles.  The way I have it in the css panel in fiddle is how it should look in your css.  It is also easier to maintain if you break it down instead of trying to lump too much together.

Comment: Alright thank you thought i could tab it out like you can in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

A CSS selector followed by a space and another selector means [2nd selector] IN A [1st selector]

So `div a` means any "a"'s within a "div"

```
#navbar a:hover,#navbar a:active { 
    background-color:#7A8B8B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#navbar a:hover,#navbar a:active { 
  background-color:#7A8B8B;
}
```

This would mean that the `a` that is in the `navbar` ID has the background color set as such